# Better way to approach a method on another class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oop, code-cleanup

I'm trying to approach a method on another class, from my main form, I already have a way that achieves this, but I don't think it is programmed very "clean".

This is the way of approaching the method with the code I currently use:

```
 private void btnConnectDevice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          Serial _serial = new Serial();
          _serial.OpenPortConnection();
    }
```

I know that the code works good, but I don't think that this is the correct way to do it. Does anybody has a clean/alternative code to achieve the same thing, only cleaner?

Thanks for your time.

EDIT:

The method on the Serial class is called OpenPortConnection, that is the Method I need to approach.

Comment: Why do you think this is approach?

Comment: Because I need to execute the code within the braces of that method on another class

Comment: As far as I can see you have an event handler and want to open a serial port. Because you construct the Serial class within the method it'll die soon when the method is finished. Make it a member (a private field) instead of a local variable.
Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Dependency injection?

Comment: Why don't you think it's the correct way to do it?

Comment: It isn't a real problem, but I don't think it is a clean way, because I directly approach the method, can I use something like a delegete and invoke the method?

Comment: To call a method on a class you either need to instantiate it or the method needs to be static. So if you don't want to instantiate a object to call OpenPortConnection can you make it static?

Comment: I made the method static, that solved my problem. Thank you

Comment: Does Serial implement IDisposable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call a method on a class you either need to instantiate it or the method needs to be static. So if you don't want to instantiate a object to call OpenPortConnection can you make it static?